# config ckeditor - config/application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

When I add the line

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

to `config/application.rb` (like in the description of [cdkeditor gem rubydoc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ckeditor/3.7.1/frames)), I get this error, when I try to start rails server:

```
> $ rails s
> /home/bhamster/Arbeitsfläche/ruby/ContentManagement/ContentManagement/config/application.rb:5:in
>
> `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for
> main:Object (NameError)   from
>
> /home/bhamster/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in
> `require'   from
>
> /home/bhamster/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in
> `block in <top (required)>'   from
>
> /home/bhamster/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
> `tap'   from
>
> /home/bhamster/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
> `<top (required)>'  from script/rails:6:in `require'  from
>
> script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

In another project it worked fine! Can't find any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
config.autoload_paths += "#{Rails.root}/app/models/ckeditor"
```

Instead of the line you posted and restart the server,....

You added the line at the wrong place,.. Try it like this placing the line in the `Application < Rails::Application` class:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

    require 'rails/all'

    if defined?(Bundler)
      # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
      Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
      # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
      # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
    end

    module ContentManagement
      class Application < Rails::Application
        config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)

        # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
        # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
        # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

        # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
        # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

        # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
        # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
        # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

        # Activate observers that should always be running.
        # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

        # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
        # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
        # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

        # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
        # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
        # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

        # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
        config.encoding = "utf-8"

        # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
        config.filter_parameters += [:password]

        # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
        config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

        # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
        # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
        # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
        # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

        # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
        # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
        # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
        # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
        config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

        # Enable the asset pipeline
        config.assets.enabled = true

        # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
        config.assets.version = '1.0'
      end
    end
```

Comment: please post the whole config file

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/78b9Q2RR](http://pastebin.com/78b9Q2RR) posted it on pastebin

Comment: I accidentially performed "gem update" instead of "bundle update" - bundler was updated from 1.1.4 -> 1.1.5 and sprockets was updated. May this can have something in common with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

does not go in `Line 5` of your `config/application.rb` *(where you mentioned having it in http://pastebin.com/78b9Q2RR)*. Move the above line anywhere **inside** the `ContentManagement::Application` class:

```
module ContentManagement
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)

    # the rest of your config
  end
end
```